# The referenced transaction does not meet the criteria for issuing a credit

Tags: python, django, authorize.net

I try to make a refund transaction via my django app using code:

```
class Handler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial_values = {
            'x_login': settings.API_LOGIN,
            'x_tran_key': settings.TRANS_KEY,
            'x_delim_data': 'TRUE',
            'x_relay_response': 'FALSE',
            'x_version': '3.1',
        }

    def send_AIM_credit(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.additional_values = {
            'x_type': 'CREDIT',
            'x_card_num': '370000000000002',
            'x_amount': '123',
            'x_description': "Refund",
            'x_trans_id': 'someid'
        }
        result = self.__send_AIM_request() 
        if result[0] in ['3', '2']:
            raise Exception("ERROR %s" % result[2], result[3])
        return result 

    def __send_AIM_request(self):
        self.initial_values.update(self.additional_values)
        logging.info(self.initial_values)
        params_string = urllib.urlencode(self.initial_values)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(settings.AIM_URL, params_string).read()
        response_list = response.split(',')
        logging.info(response_list)
        return response_list
```

I am sure that transaction which I want to refund is allowed to do that because i have refund option in authorize.net website for it. Why I cannot do that in my app? maybe something is missing?

```
AIM_URL = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'
```

Moreover in documentation i read that I don`t need full card number for credit transaction, only last 4 digits. But when I use only last 4 digits I get response that transaction cannot be found

Comment: I added x_test_reques = TRUE to request and then operation was approved. But is it a good way? I thought that when I make request to test server transaction should be approved without any additional flags. What about this card number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with security keys which I use to communicate with authorize.net I was able to make transactions but not to refund them. When I generated new keys the problem disappeared.

Comment: Damn. This stole two hours of my life until I found your post. Thank you. The guys from ANet are so mad about security that they make your life impossible. The documentation is terribly poor for a paid service. How hard is to put "you need to regenerate your transaction key" on the error code description in the docs?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I hope that they will complete their docs :)

Answer (score 5):

Refunds can only be performed through Authorize.Net if the original transaction is less then 6 months old and the amount is equal to or less then the original purchase amount. If it does not meet this criteria you cannot issue that refund.

**edit**

FYI, setting `x_test_request = TRUE` means the transaction was only a test and not actually processed.

Comment: I made my transactions yesterday. They have status settled successfully. I also make refund transactions with amount much less than orginal transaction.

Comment: Have you verified that you are sending over the correct transaction_id of the original purchase?

Comment: I take transaction id from authorize.net panel, so I am sure it is correct

Answer (score 4):

Have the same problem with my test account. I can't refund transaction created few minutes ago. You should login into your sandbox account and go to account settings -> test mode -> transaction processing set 'Test' it was 'Live' in my case. Than transaction refunded success.

Answer (score 3):

This might also be if the transaction is very new and hasn't been settled. In this case you'll want to VOID the transaction instead.

Answer (score 1):

from:

https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A567

i have found that:

- Refunds cannot be processed on transactions older than 120 days.

so i think the 6 months has been modified and is currently incorrect.  i tried issuing a REFUND for a transaction 122 days old, and i got the error message listed above.

Comment: If this is the case, one solution is to appply for the Expanded Credit Capabilities (ECC) which bypasses the time frame and transaction restrictions in the Authorize.Net system. Reference: https://hippocharging.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201321935-How-do-I-issue-a-refund-through-my-Authorize-net-account-

Answer (score 0):

I found that submitting a refund where the cardnumber string contains a credit card number AND the refTransID string contains the Auth.net TransId will produce the same error message. If the same transaction is submitted with no value in refTransID it will work.

I literally submitted the trans with this line commented out and it worked!

```
//refTransId = CreditCardTransId,
```